# MAGMA - construct local field as a quotient of polynomial ring over local field

Tags: abstract-algebra, local-field, magma-cas

I'm dealing with the following problem: I have a local field K_v, which is defined by the completion of a number field K at the place v. Moreover, I have an irreducibe polynomial f in K_v[x].

I want to define a new local field K_v[x]/(f). The command LocalField(K_v,f) yields to the error message: "precision of arument 1 must be finite". Does somebody know how I can achieve my goal or how to change the precision of Kv to a finite precision?

That would help me a lot! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The command Completion has an optional parameter Precision, which seems like it would allow you to specify a finite precision.  However, it doesn't seem to work; even setting this to be some finite number doesn't seem to change the precision of the field.  I wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: The (magma) tag should be changed to (magma-cas).

Comment: @Quasicoherent I have noticed that before too; what it actually does is set the `DefaultPrecision` of the local field, so that elements of the field are created by that precision by default. I think calling the parameter `DefaultPrecision` too would have been more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1.** The local field produced by `Completion` has infinite precision. You can make it into a fixed-precision field like so:

```
Kv2 := ChangePrecision(Kv, 20);
Lv := LocalField(Kv2, f);
```

or if $f$ is Eisenstein or inertial, you can replace the last line with

```
Lv := ext<Kv2 | f>;
```

**Option 2.** If you actually have $f(x) \in K[x]$, i.e. over the original number field, AND $f$ is Eisenstein or inertial, you can define an infinite-precision extension like so:

```
Lv := ext<Kv | map<Integers() -> PolynomialRing(K) | k :-> f>>;
```

(this option is documented here: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/485#5317)

Comment: I didn't know about the command ChangePrecision, thanks a lot!
Unfortunately, magma returns an internal error :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer:

There is one way to define a new local field via a map, the code goes as follows:

```
Z := Integers();
Kvx<x> := PolynomialRing(Kv);
m := map<Z-> Kvx | k:-> f>;
LocalField := ext<Kv | m>;
```

You can also define maps from Kv[x] to the new local field, which can be quite helpful.